# CSS Transition not working in opposite direction of style change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using transition on a paragraph to slowly make it visible when some one hovers over h1 . I am successful in doing that but the transition only works one way. When my pointer leaves the field the paragraph suddenly disappears. I don't want that I want it to transition back to hidden state.

HTML :

```
<div class="row11">
  <h1 id="html" class="h11">HTML5</h1>
  <p id="html1" class="p1"> I have strong understanding of HTML5 which makes my base strong. I have been working with HTML from the last 12 Years</p>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.row11{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: url("../images/html.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

#html{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#html1{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(182,60,56,0.9);
    padding: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
}
```

JS :

```
var headhtml = document.getElementsByClassName("h11");
var parahtml = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
headhtml[0].addEventListener('mouseover' , () => {
    parahtml[0].style.visibility = "visible" ;
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "1" ;
});

parahtml[0].addEventListener('mouseout' , () => {
    parahtml[0].style.visibility = "hidden" ;
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "0" ;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `transition` on `mouseout`:

```
parahtml[0].style.transition = "all 2s ease-out"
```

```js
var headhtml = document.getElementsByClassName("h11");
var parahtml = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
headhtml[0].addEventListener('mouseover' , () => {
    parahtml[0].style.visibility = "visible" ;
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "1" ;
});

parahtml[0].addEventListener('mouseout' , () => {
    parahtml[0].style.visibility = "hidden" ;
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "0" ;
    parahtml[0].style.transition = "all 2s ease-out";
});
```

```css
.row11{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: url("../images/html.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

#html{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#html1{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(182,60,56,0.9);
    padding: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row11">
  <h1 id="html" class="h11">HTML5</h1>
  <p id="html1" class="p1"> I have strong understanding of HTML5 which makes my base strong. I have been working with HTML from the last 12 Years</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You ! This works I tried that before but instead of all i used visibility.

Comment: @RockingEducation this doesn't need to be added with JS, simply change it on the CSS

Comment: @RockingEducation, you are most welcome....glad that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you can simply this using only CSS considering the `+` selector. You may then adjust the transition on the hover and normal state. Add a delay equal to the duration of opacity animation within the normal state and keep the initial one within the hover state:

```css
.row11 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#html {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#html1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s ease-out;
}

#html:hover + #html1 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row11">
  <h1 id="html" class="h11">HTML5</h1>
  <p id="html1" class="p1"> I have strong understanding of HTML5 which makes my base strong. I have been working with HTML from the last 12 Years</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm... actually amazed that this works. `visibility` is not a value that can be transitioned, but apparently you can still delay such values. How did I not know this?

Comment: Actually, this is just a part of the code and I have to use JS so is there a way I can achieve this without using :hover

Comment: @RockingEducation well am pretty sure that you don't have to use JS for such thing ;) but in case you need JS for this ... simply add the transition within your JS code like you did with opacity and visibility

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the trick is there:), visibility can be animated according to the list (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) even if we cannot animated like we do with opacity. And since it's on this list the delay also apply to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your visibility transition is `0s` so you need to set the visibility to `hidden` 2 seconds after the opacity on mouseout (that's how long the transition lasts) using `setTimeout`.

```css
.row11{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: url("../images/html.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    

}

#html{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#html1{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(182,60,56,0.9);
    padding: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row11">
  <h1 id="html" class="h11">HTML5</h1>
  <p id="html1" class="p1"> I have strong understanding of HTML5 which makes my base strong. I have been working with HTML for the last 12 Years</p>
</div>
<script>
var headhtml = document.getElementsByClassName("h11");
var parahtml = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
var intvl;
headhtml[0].addEventListener('mouseover' , () => {
    if(intvl){
      clearTimeout(intvl);
      intvl = null;
    }
    parahtml[0].style.visibility = "visible" ;
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "1" ;
});

parahtml[0].addEventListener('mouseout' , () => {
    parahtml[0].style.opacity = "0" ;
    intvl = setTimeout(function(){
      parahtml[0].style.visibility = "hidden" ;  
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```